# Using AspNetCore.SignalR with in AspNet MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr-hub

Is there a way to configure an AspNetCore.SignalR (.Net Core SignalR Hub Server) implemented in a netstandard2.1 project which can be hosted from an AspNet MVC 5.

I have implemented an AspNetCore SignalR Hub in netstandard2.1 project and now I want to host this hub from an MVC 5 project's startup file.

Also in another class I need the HubContext which is passed into the class through dependency injection in constructor but MVC 5 does not have dependency Injection in startup class. How can I tackle this issue?

```
public class GroupChatConnectionManager
{
        private IHubContext<GroupChatHub, IGroupChatClient> hubContext;

        public GroupChatConnectionManager(IHubContext<GroupChatHub, IGroupChatClient> hubContext)
        {
             this.hubContext = hubContext;
        }
}
```

How to achieve this injection in MVC 5  As also the IHubContext has to be registered against an interface in startup for DI to work but IHubContext is not derived from any other interface.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that. As we all known, the AspNetCore.SignalR use in ASP.NET Core applications using Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. And the Asp.net MVC 5 will use the .Net Framework, instead of .Net Core. More detail information between them, you could check [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-5.0). So, in MVC 5 application, I suggest you could refer [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc) and use Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.